# Deleting rows with cells that has "#REF" errors

Tags: excel, vba

Hi there i have an excel that contains cells with REF errors and i would like to delete rows that contain those errors than shift up the remaining cells below. I have tried various codes but only the cell itself deletes as i don't know how to incorporate the row coding for this. This is the sample code i have used.

```
  Sub Check_Ref()

   Dim rng As Range
   Dim rngError As Range

   Set rng = Sheets("Sheet4").Range("A1:Z100")
   On Error Resume Next
       Set rngError = rng.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors)
   On Error GoTo 0
   If Not rngError Is Nothing Then
       rngError.ClearContents
   End If

   'For Each cell In rng

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Range.EntireRow property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836836.aspx) to sweep the row.

You've used the terms for [Range.ClearContents method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa223828%28v=office.11%29.aspx) and [Range.Delete method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa223863(v=office.11).aspx) interchangeably. They are NOT the same thing.

```
If Not rngError Is Nothing Then
     'rngError.EntireRow.ClearContents
     rngError.EntireRow.Delete
End If
```

Comment: Small point: this will fail if there are more than one non-adjacent #Ref errors on the same row

Comment: That's a very good point @chrisneilsen and one that should be considered and consistent before blanketly deleting rows based upon one column's value.